# Dubbio sul genere del sostantivo "esponenziale"

Tags: gender, mathematics

L'aggettivo *esponenziale* può essere sicuramente sia femminile (*funzione e.*, *curva e.*, ecc.) sia maschile (e.g. *modo e.*). Dato che l'aggettivo concorda sempre col sostantivo basta sapere il genere del sostantivo per scoprire quello assunto da *esponenziale*.

Il problema sussiste nel momento in cui *esponenziale* venga usato come sostantivo: la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/esponenziale/) ed il [Nuovo De Mauro (Internazionale)](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/esponenziale) suggeriscono che sia maschile, [Hoepli (Repubblica)](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/E/esponenziale.html) suggerisce che sia femminile ed infine il [Sabatini-Coletti (Corriere)](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/E/esponenziale.shtml) e la [Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=esponenziale) non considerano neanche l'uso come sostantivo.

Degno di nota è che per Treccani e Nuovo De Mauro, *esponenziale* è un tipo particolare di funzione esponenziale, cioè quella funzione esponenziale che ha come base il numero di Nepero. L'esempio del dizionario Hoepli, *curva e.* è invece, secondo me, completamente errato dato che in questo caso *esponenziale* viene usato come aggettivo.

Comment: Quello del dizionario Hoepli non è un esempio; è, secondo loro, una definizione (asseriscono cioè che “esponenziale” venga usato ell[itticamente] nel senso di “curva esponenziale”). Io comunque non ho mai sentito il sostantivo “esponenziale” usato al femminile, né per indicare una curva.

Comment: In ogni caso, fanno più testo il Treccani e il De Mauro che quello che ti posso dire io o altri sconosciuti su Internet. :)

Comment: @DaG Come sostantivo, personalmente, l'ho usato sempre al femminile prima che mi venisse posto il quesito. Per quanto riguarda _curva e._, è più che comune in un contesto scientifico.

Comment: @DaG Non è che mi fido ciecamente del giudizio di sconosciuti, speravo in qualche fonte autorevole che mi è sfuggita che chiarisse il dubbio. :)

Comment: M'ero spiegato male: certo che “curva esponenziale” è frequentissimo; è “esponenziale” da solo come sostantivo per indicare la curva che non ho mai sentito in tutti gli anni di università e di dottorato.

Comment: Un'ultima considerazione: di “fonti autorevoli” sul lessico italiano difficilmente troveremo di meglio del Treccani e del De Mauro. Purtroppo i testi scritti da matematici, fisici, informatici sono paradossalmente molto meno autorevoli linguisticamente: basta vedere gli anglismi e gli accenti a casaccio di cui sono gremite le dispense di queste discipline. D'altro canto, mettendo insieme le nostre esperienze e i vari dizionari (che, ricordo, registrano gli usi, non li decidono), potremmo concludere semplicemente che si usano entrambi i generi.

Comment: @DaG Non generalizzerei. [Qui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE1tX.png) puoi vedere che adopero *esponenziale* come sostantivo di genere maschile. E cerco di non mettere accenti a casaccio e anglismi gratuiti. Adopero anche il congiuntivo.

Comment: Sull'esponenziale la pensiamo allo stesso modo, @egreg, anch'io lo uso solo al maschile e per indicare la funzione. E raccolgo il tuo giusto invito a non generalizzare e mi correggo: “basta vedere gli anglismi e gli accenti a casaccio di cui sono gremite alcune dispense di queste discipline”.

Comment: @DaG Ad essere sinceri, il dubbio mi è stato proposto dalla mia ragazza il cui professore è rimasto a ponderare per un minuto la lavagna indeciso se l'articolo indeterminativo volesse o meno l'apostrofo seguito da _esponenziale_ prima di chiedere consiglio alla classe. Questo per confermare che anche coloro che hanno usato un termine per 30 anni in contesti accademici possano avere dei dubbi.

Comment: Trovo molto curioso che in italiano il numero *e* si chiami numero di Nepero.

Comment: @Charo in realtà non ho mai capito perché nel resto del mondo venga chiamato numero di Eulero se non per il fatto che probabilmente fu semplicemente il primo a denotarlo colla “e”. :)

Comment: @Charo È infatti molto curioso, visto che Napier (Nepero) non aveva la più pallida idea della sua esistenza e del legame con i suoi logaritmi (che fra l'altro erano alquanto diversi da come li consideriamo oggi). Per la verità storica, fu Jacques Bernoulli il primo a considerarlo. Non è l'unica stranezza: in Italia è comune attribuire a Lazare Carnot il teorema del coseno, che in Francia chiamano di Al-Kashi e, ovviamente, precede Carnot di alcuni secoli.

Comment: @egreg: E immagino che questo di chiamarli Eulero, Nepero, Cartesio, ecc. (cosa che ho anche sempre trovata molto curiosa) invece di Euler, Napier, Descartes, ecc. sia a causa del latino.

Answer (score 7):

È solo un'indicazione aneddotica, ma nella mia pur limitata esperienza di matematico ho visto il termine *esponenziale* per indicare la funzione usato unicamente al maschile, come hanno indicato anche @egreg e @DaG nei commenti.

Per esempio, il [wikibook di matematica](https://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Matematica_per_le_superiori/Funzioni_esponenziale_e_logaritmica) usa anche lui il maschile, così come innumerevoli dispense. Una ricerca su Google Scholar di [esponenziale complesso](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22esponenziale+complesso%22&btnG=) ed [esponenziale complessa](https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22esponenziale+complessa%22&btnG=) sembra almeno suggerire che la prima forma sia di gran lunga la più comune.

Se qualcuno lo usasse al femminile sarebbe sicuramente comprensibile, ma non comune.

Answer (score -2):

A logica, "esponenziale" deve essere solo coniugata al femminile. Deriva da una classe di funzioni (appunto, f. esponenziali) che godono di particolari proprietà, e le medesime, almeno in italiano, non hanno nemmeno un sinonimo al maschile (qualcuno potrebbe obiettare il fatto che esiste anche il concetto di funzionale, ma è qualcosa che trascende il caso di specie).

Caso particolare, quello citato dell'esponenziale complesso, che è molto più colloquiale che altro - propriamente si parla di f. e. complessa.

Comment: Non vedo perché _a logica_ dovrebbe essere solo femminile. L'aggettivo prende il genere del sostantivo, è solo un caso che _curva_ e _funzione_ siano entrambi femminili. Inoltre _esponenziale_ può essere usato come aggettivo di sostantivi maschili come _modo_. Per finire, non capisco perché _e. complesso_ debba essere considerato colloquiale dal momento che _esponenziale_ come sostantivo indica appunto una particolare (sul fatto che ne indichi una particolare o una generale si potrebbe dibattere) _funzione esponenziale_.

Comment: Mi spiace, ma qui devo essere in disaccordo. La pratica val più della grammatica, per così dire, e in pratica il sostantivo *esponenziale* è sempre maschile, in articoli formali o meno.

Comment: Non sapevo che una funzione fosse un sostantivo maschile.